# How to create a single sign on (SSO) service for multiple domains with ASP.net Identity?

Tags: single-sign-on, asp.net-identity-2

My most recent task is to create a Single Sign On (SSO) service that would serve about 10 websites, and three domains - all using Asp.net mvc 5 and Asp.net Identity.  I have come across quite a few helpful hints that allow you to carry authorization between subdomains, but none across domains.

Short Version:

User Hits

1. www.CompanyDomain.com
2. Gets Redirected to SSO.CompanyDomain.com
3. Gets Redirected back to www.Company.com
4. Clicks on link to www.CompanyDomainAlt-1.com
5. SSO.CompanyDomain.com somehow authenticates user on www.CompanyDomainAlt-1.com
6. Clicks on link to www.CompanyDomainAlt2.com
7. SSO.CompanyDomain.com somehow authenticates user on www.CompanyDomainAlt-2.com

Is there some way to do this that is already baked into the ASP.net Identity 2.0 system?

Comment: Check if this can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR4KXDK4HWE

Comment: Alas - those are for different subdomains, not different domains.